# How to convert a dataframe into a tree data structure

Tags: python, recursion

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to convert into a tree data structure so that I can then use something like [TreeView](https://mui.com/x/react-tree-view/) to show the tree structure in my application.

Preferably, I want to use recursion to build the data structure. I have tried without recursion, but am coming up short because I can't get the fully nested structure I'm after. Everything I've researched has examples for tree structure recursion, but I'm stuck because I have a list of tree structures.

The expected output is this:

```
[
  {
    "section": "1.0",
    "title": "Main section",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "1.1",
        "title": "One subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "1.2",
        "title": "Another subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "1.3",
        "title": "And another subsection"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section": "2.0",
    "title": "The second main section",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "2.1",
        "title": "A subsection of the second main section",
        "children": [
          {
            "section": "2.1.1",
            "title": "A sub subsection"
          },
          {
            "section": "2.1.2",
            "title": "Another sub subsection",
            "children": [
              {
                "section": "2.1.2.1",
                "title": "I am a deep subsection"
              },
              {
                "section": "2.1.2.2",
                "title": "I am another deep subsection"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Here's some working sample code and the output of it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = [
    ['1.0', 'Main section'],
    ['1.1', 'One subsection'],
    ['1.2', 'Another subsection'],
    ['1.3', 'And another subsection'],
    ['2.0', 'The second main section'],
    ['2.1', 'A subsection of the second main section'],
    ['2.1.1', 'A sub subsection'],
    ['2.1.2', 'Another sub subsection'],
    ['2.1.2.1', 'I am a deep subsection'],
    ['2.1.2.2', 'I am another deep subsection'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['section', 'title'])

# Add parent column
def add_parent(val):
    parent = val.split('.')[:-1]

    if len(parent) == 1:
        parent.append('0')
    
    parent = '.'.join(parent)
    
    if parent == val:
        return None
    return parent

df['parent'] = df['section'].apply(lambda x: add_parent(x))

records = []
for row in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    if row['section'] in df['parent'].unique():
        row['children'] = []
        
        for value, dataframe in df.groupby('parent'):
            if row['section'] == value:
                for val in dataframe.to_dict(orient='records'):
                    val.pop('parent')
                    row['children'].append(val)
    
        row.pop('parent')
        records.append(row)

json_str = json.dumps(records, indent=2)
```

```
print(json_str)

[
  {
    "section": "1.0",
    "title": "Main section",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "1.1",
        "title": "One subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "1.2",
        "title": "Another subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "1.3",
        "title": "And another subsection"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section": "2.0",
    "title": "The second main section",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "2.1",
        "title": "A subsection of the second main section"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section": "2.1",
    "title": "A subsection of the second main section",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "2.1.1",
        "title": "A sub subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "2.1.2",
        "title": "Another sub subsection"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section": "2.1.2",
    "title": "Another sub subsection",
    "children": [
      {
        "section": "2.1.2.1",
        "title": "I am a deep subsection"
      },
      {
        "section": "2.1.2.2",
        "title": "I am another deep subsection"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

At first it looks to me as you lack one level on nesting, so if you know that it will be fixed number, maybe just check the loops if they go to the level that they need to. But if you would like to use a more general approach I would recommend something like DFS/BFS algorithm for traversing your already existing "adjacency list".

Comment: The example I provided is only missing one level of nesting, but the actual data will have more levels of nesting, which is why I'm interested in a recursive solution.